# How to make visible only last 3 characters from Excel cell

Tags: excel

I have a row that contains different numbers. first 5 characters from each cell are equal, difference is only in last 3 characters (Example: 10265**083**, 10265**154**, 10265**360**).

I don't need to make the cell so wide as length of the number, because the sheet will be too large visually. So I need to see only last 3 characters in cell. In formula bar should be the whole number, because I need to use full number for further formulas.

Is it possible to do something like this?

[image: How it should be]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all kinds of cell formatting, I didn't find any way only to show the last three digits. Therefore I opt for another approach: just create a helper column, containing the following formula: `=MOD(J7,1000)`.

Comment: Thank you. it is a good variant. But in other cells I need to use the full name from this cell for another formulas. I will add this info in the question

Comment: In that case, you just take the information from the original cell, or am I missing something?

Comment: Theoretically, I can use another cell for the full number, but I will have to change formulas in the whole sheet. It is not so big work, I can copy then. Thank you